# C++ vector of char vectors cannot be printed

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a c++ vector of char vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<char>> ref`
After putting chars in it (size increases, so chars are there) I cannot print it.

By calling `this->ref.back().back()` it correctly prints the last char. But if I do  `ref.at(0).at(pos)` or  `ref[0].at(pos)` or  `ref[0][pos]`
nothing is printed.

Chars are put in as follows:

```
while (infile>>c)
    {
        if (c != '>') {
            ref.back().push_back(c);
            curSeqPos++;

        }
        else {
            infile.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
            ref.push_back(std::vector<char>(USHRT_MAX));

            curSeq++;
            curSeqPos = 0;
        }
     }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am a real newbie to C++ and probably missed a reference somewhere. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `pos` equal to?

Comment: This is the kind of question that is greatly improved by a [MCVE]. It's hard to know where your mistake is without seeing what you wrote.

Comment: sorry, I am reading from a file and want to store every char in an array / vector. if a line starts with ">" this line should be ignored and a new char vector should be created

Comment: Wait... are you trying to directly print the buffer of a `vector` like a string?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`?  Then you can use `getline` to read in entire lines and simply check if the first character is `'>'` and if it is not then add it to the vector.

Comment: @InternetAussie hm, i think so

Comment: @NathanOliver because I need to read every single character. this part works btw..

Comment: @cruxi That will not work unless there is a null terminator at the end, or you put the characters into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and print that.

Comment: The printing code "doesn't work" but you don't show it to us? Present your [MCVE]. This is not optional.

Comment: @InternetAussie: Not so.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Educate me.

Comment: @InternetAussie: What in particular would you like to learn today?

Comment: `std::vector<char>(USHRT_MAX)` is a vector containing `USHRT_MAX` characters. When you `push_back` you add a new character at the end of the vector. The first character you `push_back` would be at index `USHRT_MAX`, the following at `USHRT_MAX + 1`, etc. Did you mean to use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition _"That will not work unless there is a null terminator at the end, or you put the characters into a `std::string` and print that."_ _"Not so."_ Why not so?

Comment: @InternetAussie: Because there are many other ways to print data? Loop over the characters and print them individually (as the OP is apparently doing) or just `std::cout.write(&vec[0], vec.size())`? Or near-infinite variations on this theme. You are not confined to a "`std::string` or C-string" dichotomy.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I see. I was just throwing out ideas. I didn't mean that the two ways I suggested are the *only* ways to print data :) I am well aware of other methods.

Comment: @InternetAussie: Okay. Your phrase _"that will not work unless"_ implied that you were suggesting precisely that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux with you help, I could fix it. but thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really make out a lot from your code but from this `std::vector<std::vector<char>> ref`, ref is a 2-D array of vectors.

Since `ref` is a 2-D array of vectors of char, every index of ref e.g., `ref[1]` will have to hold a vector of char. You'll have to do just that, that is create a separate vector of char to the indices of ref else any attempt to print content at that index will result in SIGSEGV error.

Also, you can't do `ref[0][1] = 'd';` , except at ref[0] since you've already assigned a vector of char to it else you'll get SIGSEGV error.

```
 std::vector<std::vector<char>> ref(7);
    std::vector<char> ref1(7);

    //try
   //ref[0][0] = 'f'; SIGSEGV  error cus ref[0] is empty   

    ref1[0] = 'r';
    ref[0] = ref1;
    ref[0][3] = 'g'; //valid

    std::cout << ref[0][0]; // r
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's syntax, so they already know this. This is not a useful answer.

Comment: @ BoundaryImposition i edited to explain possible reason why cruxi got her errors

Answer (score 0):

Giving my best to be constructive, here an example that works:

```
#include <string> // for stdout, putc
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<char>> const slist = 
    {{'o','n','e'},{'t','w','o'},{'t','h','r','e','e'}};

int main() {
    const int sz = slist[1].size();
    for(int p=0; p<sz; p++) {
        putc(slist[1][p],stdout);
    }
    putc('\n',stdout);
    return(0);
}
```

This prints "two\n" to stdout. You cannot use printf("%s\n",slist[1]) on your character vector as one could possibly expect. This does not even raise a warning but prints just gibberish. Cout << slist[1] of the iostreams fails with a type cast error.

Are we getting towards where your problem is? Please direct us.